# Gradle: Project dependencies from file

Tags: gradle

I'm fairly new to Gradle, and am enamored by its task-driven approach and customizability. So I have a question that hopefully helps me understand how to do something beyond the basics.

Suppose I have a simple text file that contains information about a project's dependencies.  For example, something like

```
- dependency1
    from: 'foobar'
    version: '1'
- dependency2
    from: 'foobaz'
    version: '1'
```

Note that these are not I have some code that would, from this file, generate a file along the lines as follows:

```
compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang 2.6'
testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4'
```

Is there a way to configure my project so that my project's dependencies are taken from this file (not exclusively)?

Do note that the text file is also used to generate other artifacts that are used by other tasks (for example, a file to be added to a Docker container), so while it may be possible to, say, declare the dependencies normally and generate the text file instead, it is not a trivial process to do so at this time.

Comment: You might be interested in [gradle-maven-share](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-share) and [gradle-maven-transform](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-transform) plugins. The first adds dependencies to the gradle model by parsing pom.xml. The second generates gradle files from pom.xml which are subsequently "applied"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write your own groovy function that parses the file and creates a List. Then you can pass this map to the dependencies closures:

```
List<String> compileLibraries() {
    // ... parse yaml and return list
}

dependencies {
   compile compileLibraries()
}
```

Also, to use a yaml-parsing library, consider setting up a custom gradle subproject in the special buildSrc subfolder and writing your helper function there.

See this old post for more details: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/programmatically-adding-dependencies/7575/12

And here for buildSrc projects:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:build_sources